# Facing issue when starting the server in Gem fire

Tags: gemfire

after running sequence of the commands:
1.gfsh

2.start locator --name=locator1

3.start pulse

4.start server --name=server1 --server-port=40411

The Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 1. Please refer to the log file in /Users/nirkumar/server1 for full details.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.geode.SystemConnectException: Unable to join the distributed system in 66050ms

```
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DistributionImpl.start(DistributionImpl.java:184)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DistributionImpl.createDistribution(DistributionImpl.java:220)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterDistributionManager.<init>(ClusterDistributionManager.java:464)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterDistributionManager.<init>(ClusterDistributionManager.java:497)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterDistributionManager.create(ClusterDistributionManager.java:326)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.initialize(InternalDistributedSystem.java:779)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.access$200(InternalDistributedSystem.java:135)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem$Builder.build(InternalDistributedSystem.java:3036)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.connectInternal(InternalDistributedSystem.java:290)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.connectInternal(InternalDistributedSystem.java:216)

at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.InternalCacheBuilder.createInternalDistributedSystem(InternalCacheBuilder.java:346)

at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)

at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.InternalCacheBuilder.create(InternalCacheBuilder.java:157)

at org.apache.geode.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:142)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DefaultServerLauncherCacheProvider.createCache(DefaultServerLauncherCacheProvider.java:52)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.createCache(ServerLauncher.java:894)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:809)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.run(ServerLauncher.java:739)

at org.apache.geode.distributed.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:256)
```

---

attaching log from server1 as well

info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.125 IST server1  tid=0x1] initializing InternalDataSerializer with 7 services

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.137 IST server1  tid=0x1] Serial Queue info : THROTTLE_PERCENT: 0.75 SERIAL_QUEUE_BYTE_LIMIT :41943040 SERIAL_QUEUE_THROTTLE :31457280 TOTAL_SERIAL_QUEUE_BYTE_LIMIT :83886080 TOTAL_SERIAL_QUEUE_THROTTLE :31457280 SERIAL_QUEUE_SIZE_LIMIT :20000 SERIAL_QUEUE_SIZE_THROTTLE :15000

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.256 IST server1  tid=0x1] Starting membership services

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.336 IST server1  tid=0x1] Established local address 192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.336 IST server1  tid=0x1] JGroups channel created (took 79ms)

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.355 IST server1  tid=0x1] GemFire P2P Listener started on /192.168.1.2:47181

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.356 IST server1 <Geode Failure Detection Server thread 1> tid=0x1f] Started failure detection server thread on /192.168.1.2:54079.

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.381 IST server1  tid=0x1] received FindCoordinatorResponse(coordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, fromView=true, viewId=10, registrants=[192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001], senderId=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, network partition detection enabled=true, locators preferred as coordinators=true, view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001])

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.382 IST server1  tid=0x1] Locator's address indicates it is part of a distributed system so I will not become membership coordinator on this attempt to join

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.382 IST server1  tid=0x1] findCoordinator chose 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 out of these possible coordinators: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.382 IST server1  tid=0x1] Discovery state after looking for membership coordinator is locatorsContacted=1; findInViewResponses=0; alreadyTried=[]; registrants=[]; possibleCoordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000; viewId=10; hasContactedAJoinedLocator=true; view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001]; responses=[]

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.382 IST server1  tid=0x1] found possible coordinator 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000

[info 2021/09/21 14:34:53.382 IST server1  tid=0x1] Attempting to join the distributed system through coordinator 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 using address 192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.405 IST server1  tid=0x1] received FindCoordinatorResponse(coordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, fromView=true, viewId=10, registrants=[192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001], senderId=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, network partition detection enabled=true, locators preferred as coordinators=true, view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001])

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.405 IST server1  tid=0x1] Locator's address indicates it is part of a distributed system so I will not become membership coordinator on this attempt to join

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.405 IST server1  tid=0x1] findCoordinator chose 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 out of these possible coordinators: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.406 IST server1  tid=0x1] Discovery state after looking for membership coordinator is locatorsContacted=1; findInViewResponses=0; alreadyTried=[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]; registrants=[192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001]; possibleCoordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000; viewId=10; hasContactedAJoinedLocator=true; view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001]; responses=[]

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.406 IST server1  tid=0x1] found possible coordinator 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:35.406 IST server1  tid=0x1] Probable coordinator is still 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 - waiting for a join-response

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.418 IST server1  tid=0x1] received FindCoordinatorResponse(coordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, fromView=true, viewId=10, registrants=[192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001], senderId=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000, network partition detection enabled=true, locators preferred as coordinators=true, view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001])

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.418 IST server1  tid=0x1] Locator's address indicates it is part of a distributed system so I will not become membership coordinator on this attempt to join

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.418 IST server1  tid=0x1] findCoordinator chose 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 out of these possible coordinators: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.419 IST server1  tid=0x1] Discovery state after looking for membership coordinator is locatorsContacted=1; findInViewResponses=0; alreadyTried=[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]; registrants=[192.168.1.2(server1:46275):41001]; possibleCoordinator=192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000; viewId=10; hasContactedAJoinedLocator=true; view=View[192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000|10] members: [192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000]  crashed: [192.168.1.2(server1:43160):41001]; responses=[]

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.419 IST server1  tid=0x1] found possible coordinator 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:47.419 IST server1  tid=0x1] Probable coordinator is still 192.168.1.2(locator1:1904:locator):41000 - waiting for a join-response

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:59.426 IST server1  tid=0x1] Stopping membership services

[info 2021/09/21 14:35:59.427 IST server1 <Geode Failure Detection Server thread 1> tid=0x1f] GMSHealthMonitor server thread exiting

Comment: Are you connected to a VPN when running these commands? If so, try without the VPN active.

Comment: after I am not connected to vpn, same issue is happening..

Comment: I have attached the log from server1 as well